# How are managed exceptions handled by the OS?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Does anyone have a paper, a link, or something like that, that explains the mechanics between C# managed exceptions and the OS? As I understand, the OS sees the managed C# exceptions as one exception. I want to know more about how the exceptions is treated by the OS, before it is handed to the managed program and caught.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens at OS level when a .net program exits due to an uncaught exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949410/what-happens-at-os-level-when-a-net-program-exits-due-to-an-uncaught-exception)

Comment: @Nacereddine, that's about uncaught exceptions, this about exceptions that are "handed to the managed program and caught."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Microsoft's .NET Framework, C# exceptions work through [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657.aspx) (see note about SEH [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)).

Mono has a different approach.  You can read its [documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aRuntime%3aDocumentation%3aExceptionHandling).